# Autoscroll Swift Chart

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-charts

I'm having a play with the new swift charts capability built into iOS 17. The new version provides scrolling capabilities. I've managed to get a sample of this working and the chart can be manually scrolled horizontally by specifying `.chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)`. However I need my to chart to scroll programatically along the xAxis.

Essentially I need to have a button trigger the chart to scroll and stop again when the button is clicked again. This will require a level of customisation also, for example the ability to specify the speed of the scrolling.

**What I've discovered.**

I have looked for a way to specify the xPosition of the chart but have only discovered a way to read it using `.chartScrollPosition`.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts



struct ChartData: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    
    var title: String
    var startTime: Double
    var endTime: Double
    
    init(startTime: Double, duration: Double, title: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.startTime = startTime
        self.endTime = startTime + duration
    }
}

var data2: [ChartData] = [
    ChartData(startTime: 2.0, duration: 5.0, title: "First"),
    ChartData(startTime: 750.0, duration: 30.6, title: "Second")
]

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var chartPosition = Double(0.0)
    @State var chartScale = Double(10.0)
    @State var markPosition = Double(0.0)
    @State var duration = Double(750.0 + 30.6)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack{
                Text("Position: \(chartPosition)")
            }
            HStack{
                Slider(value: $chartScale, in: 1...360)
                Text("\(chartScale)")
            }
            HStack{
                Slider(value: $markPosition, in: 0...duration)
                Text("\(markPosition)")
            }
            Chart{
                ForEach(data2) { item in
                    RectangleMark(
                        xStart: .value("TL Start", item.startTime),
                        xEnd: .value("End", item.endTime),
                        y: .value("Title", item.title)
                    )
                }
            }
            .chartXVisibleDomain(length: chartScale)
            .chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)
            .chartYAxis(.hidden)
            .chartScrollPosition(x: $chartPosition)
        
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `... chart to scroll programatically along the xAxis`,
you could try this approach, simply updating the `chartPosition` value.

For example, recycling your current slider,

```
 Slider(value: $markPosition, in: 0...duration)
     .onChange(of: markPosition) {
         chartPosition = markPosition  // <--- here
     }
```

as you change the slider, the chart will scroll to the chosen position.

Or a specific slider

```
Slider(value: $chartPosition, in: 0...duration)
```

You can use the same approach using a `Button`, just update the `chartPosition` value. Note you can futher customise the scrolling using `chartScrollTargetBehavior`.

EDIT-1:

to `have a button trigger the chart to scroll and stop again when the button is clicked again`,
you could use something like this example code:

declare:

```
 @State var doScroll = false
 @State var speed = 2.0
```

and in the body:

```
 HStack {
     Button("scroll >") {
         doScroll.toggle()
         Task { @MainActor in
             for _ in 0..<50  {  // <-- todo
                 if doScroll {
                     chartPosition += speed  // <-- more logic here
                     try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.1))  // <-- adjust
                 } else {
                     break
                 }
             }
         }
     }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
 }
```